# Is Dun / dunning archaic?

Tags: archaicisms, finance

> *verb* (used with object), dunned, dun·ning.
>   to make repeated and insistent demands upon, especially for the payment of a debt.
>
> *noun*
>   a person, especially a creditor, who duns another.
>   a demand for payment, especially a written one.

(dictionary.com)

The noun «dun» is marked as archaic by The Oxford Dictionary of English.

Is "Dunning" the most widely used/precise term (and understandable by most people today) as a heading/menu entry in a modern solution to list and edit formal invoice reminders/demands? Or are there more natural alternatives?

Comment: Unpaid invoice duplicates are usually marked "reminder" or "final demand". I have never seen "dunning" used.

Comment: Not at all what you're asking, but 'dun' is a not-archaic but specialty term for a particular grayish-brown usually for horses.

Comment: It is a well known, precise term in accounting. (Accounting software discusses "dunning letters" at pages like https://www.accountingtools.com/articles/what-is-a-dunning-letter.html.) However, it may not be "understandable by most people day." I can think of several accounting terms that have a precise meaning which will escape most people.

Comment: Please link and attribute your quote. Also, "I've seen dictionary entries where this word is marked as archaic." It would help if you listed these dictionaries, to help avoid needless repeat searches. // If some dictionaries mark a usage as 'archaic' while others don't, it looks reasonable to assume it's borderline. And best avoided.

Comment: I grew up being dunned for a quarter most nights, because my mom is treacherous at cards.

Comment: Do please bear in mind that the Oxford Dictionary of English is NOT the Oxford English Dictionary. Though both are published by the Oxford University Press, the former is a one-volume publication the latter is both online and in print form which runs to something like thirty volumes. The OED - on the matter of the noun *dun*, meaning "a creditor who makes repeated demands for payment" says nothing about it being "archaic" - though I must say that while I am aware of the verb, I have never before encountered the word as a noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask if the expression is ***archaic***.

Well the OED has an example from 2014, from the *New York Times*.

> 2014   N.Y. Times (Nexis) 7 Dec. (Business section) 3   I am now being
>   dunned for $80.63. (Hide quotations)

Not sure what your criteria are for *archaic*, but clearly it is not something that belongs entirely to an earlier century.

Comment: This appears to be an American English usage only.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the most helpful answer, mostly because of your comment below another answer here. The expression might be rarely used or arguably unknown colloquially, but it looks like it is the best and most precise choice for the intended use. Thanks!

Comment: @rubjo Thankyou. I would only add, what I have now included in another comment, that I have never encountered its use as a noun.

Answer (score 0):

If "dunning letters" were archaic I would not expect to see instructions on the Internet on sending them via email.

We send dunning letters to delinquent customers.  I would not call this archaic (USA).

https://help-2018r1.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Wiki/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=fa034fe5-7633-4012-801f-974405be58d7

```
**To Set Up a Dunning Letter Mailing**
```